# Php isn't updating my database

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am building a website which contains reports to publish and update,
I have the following codes which after surfing the web and checking for solutions no help at all.

After selecting the reference number this page grabs the content from the database and echo it in text area for the user to update them.
Here is a sample:

second page:

```
<form method="post"  action="./../php/updated_preview_report.php">
ending:
<textarea id="endings" name="endings"  placeholder="ending" > <?php echo $endings; ?></textarea> 
<input type="submit" name="preview" value="ending" />
</form>
```

the `updated_preview_report.php`page:

```
<?php
include 'connectionfile.php' ;

$ref= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ref']);
$titl= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['titles']);
$kind= $_POST['kindy'];
$subjec= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['subjects']);
$caus= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['causes']);
$solutio= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['solutions']);
$penalt= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['penaltys']);
$not= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['notes']);
$endin= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['endings']);
session_start();

$sql = "UPDATE report SET title = '$titl', type = '$kind', subject = '$subjec', cause = '$caus', solution = '$solutio', penalty = '$penalt' , note = '$not', ending = '$endin'  WHERE reference = $ref";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

?>
```

When i echo any of the updated values such as `$title` for example, it does show the updated value

**Note that no error was reported/shown.**

So why isn't this query updating my database?

My knowledge in web development is poor, so easy on me and thank you in advance!

Comment: You should check for errors after execute the query.

Comment: echo your SQL statement and check your data

Comment: @jens i did check for errors using error_reporting and there was nothing to display, but it got fixed, thank you for helping

Comment: It is better to use prepared statements.

Comment: I don't get the mysqli then continuing to code like this

Comment: Well it is more of a mixture of non-functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the variable you're using, and use the concat `.` operator in order to string together the query.

e.g. something like

```
$str = "SELECT " . $var1 . " FROM " . $var2;
```

So this

```
$sql = "UPDATE report SET title = '$titl', type = '$kind', subject = '$subjec', cause = '$caus', solution = '$solutio', penalty = '$penalt' , note = '$not', ending = '$endin'  WHERE reference = $ref";
```

becomes this

```
$sql = "UPDATE report SET title = '" . $titl . "', type = '" . $kind . "', subject = '" . $subjec. "', cause = '" . $caus . "', solution = '" . $solutio . "', penalty = '" . $penalt . "' , note = '" . $not . "', ending = '" . $endin . "'  WHERE reference = '" . $ref . "'";
```

You're not getting errors because `UPDATE report SET title = '$titl', type = '$kind', subject = '$subjec', cause = '$caus', solution = '$solutio', penalty = '$penalt' , note = '$not', ending = '$endin'  WHERE reference = $ref` is valid syntax.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to set `isset` if you are posting, to make sure you are posting something.

```
if (isset($_POST['endings'])
```

You don't need to set a session to Update the database

```
session_start(); //You don't need to start session, don't see any reason
```

You should add followig code to check errors

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

And Finally your code will look like

```
<?php
    include 'connectionfile.php' ;
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1'); 
    if (isset($_POST['endings']) {
            $ref= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ref']);
            $titl= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['titles']);
            $kind= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['kindy']);
            $subjec= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['subjects']);
            $caus= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['causes']);
            $solutio= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['solutions']);
            $penalt= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['penaltys']);
            $not= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['notes']);
            $endin= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['endings']);
            session_start(); //You don't need to start session, don't see any reason 
            $sql = "UPDATE report SET title = '$titl', type = '$kind', subject = '$subjec', cause = '$caus', solution = '$solutio', penalty = '$penalt' , note = '$not', ending = '$endin'  WHERE reference = '$ref'";
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysql_error());
    }
?>
```

Comment: He will still have an error where his $sql string is incorrectly formatted. See my answer.

Comment: yes may be, but i m not gona edit the code in answer, reason, it may not be working for OP but it's working code, i used same above code countless time without any error and if the code in your answer is the only  code then there won't be 4 answers of this questions but code in your answer fuly address the OP issue so it marked correct but it doesn't mean the code in rest of 3 answers are wrong. so for future readers I'm leaving it as to it so may b it address someone else problem, peace

Answer (score 1):

There should be errors since you are using both "`mysql`" and "`mysqli`" connection types. Cannot say which method is implemented in your connection file since it is not provided. Use only one type. If the problem is not solved,  Try adding

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

to the top of your page. (Above `include 'connectionfile.php' ;`)

This will show any errors that is occurring in your code (if it is hidden).

Comment: A great first start for the OP. Then onward to prepared stmts then pdo named parameters

Answer (score 1):

You should add the backtick on columns since some of them are reserved MySQL words.

```
 $sql = "UPDATE report SET 
                            `title` = $titl, 
                            `type` = $kind, 
                            `subject` = $subjec, 
                            `cause` = $caus, 
                            `solution` = $solutio, 
                            `penalty` = $penalt , 
                            `note` = $not, 
                            `ending` = $endin  
        WHERE `reference` = $ref";
```

Reserved words are found on this page: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/keywords.html